# Spire - set my own font in PDF field

Tags: c#, pdf, spire

I am using spire to generate a pdf document. All works well but now I want to change the font of one of the text fields to my own font. Any ideas how to do this? My code to generate pdf as as below

```
 using (PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument())
 {
     doc.LoadFromFile(MyFileTemplate);
     PdfFormWidget formWidget = doc.Form as PdfFormWidget;

     (formWidget.FieldsWidget["UserID"] as PdfTextBoxFieldWidget).Text = Username;
     (formWidget.FieldsWidget["Name"] as PdfTextBoxFieldWidget).Text =Name;
     (formWidget.FieldsWidget["Address"] as PdfTextBoxFieldWidget).Text = Address;

     doc.SaveToFile(MyFilePath);
}
```

I tried using

```
PdfTrueTypeFont font = new PdfTrueTypeFont("My Font Name", 10f);
(formWidget.FieldsWidget["Address"] as PdfTextBoxFieldWidget).Text.Font = font;
```

But this dint work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
PdfTrueTypeFont font = new PdfTrueTypeFont("My Font Name", 10f);
(formWidget.FieldsWidget["Address"] as PdfTextBoxFieldWidget).Font = font;
```

Please Mark as Answer if it solves the problem.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your method only works for the textbox created by the Adobe. If you draw the text using Spire.Pdf, please change the code as below:

```
PdfForm formWidget = doc.Form as PdfForm;
PdfTrueTypeFont font = new PdfTrueTypeFont("My Font Name", 10f);
(formWidget.Fields["Address"] as PdfTextBoxField).Font = font;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now your code works well with the newest hotfix([Spire.pdf3.9.82](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/download-pdf-for-net-now.html)), you can try it.

I'm an employee of e-iceblue.